# create-react-app 2.0, how to use absolute path import in sass/scss files?

Tags: reactjs, sass, create-react-app, react-scripts

I am using [creacte-react-app 2.0.0-next.66cc7a90](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-app), which already has [support for Sass/Scss files](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/4195)

however with default relative import in Sass/Scss files, i have to use code like 
`@import "../../../../../styles/variables/_variables.scss";`

instead I want to use absolute import so i can import with code 
`@import "styles/variables/_variables.scss";`

I know one way to acheve so is to update options

```
{
   loader: "sass-loader",
   options: {
        includePaths: ["absolute/path/a", "absolute/path/b"]
 }
```

but I want to do it without ejecting, how can i do it? using react-app-rewired?

Comment: File an issue and let's discuss!

Comment: @DanAbramov thanks so much for the quick reply! I have filed an issue here https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4494

Comment: For the people coming from Google: Append your paths to the `SASS_PATH` environment variable in `.env`.

Answer (score 5):

Add the required root include paths to `SASS_PATH` environment variable.

It can be set either when you run the `yarn` or `npm` commands or in a `.env` file.

### Example

```
// my-component.jsx
import React from 'react';
import './my-component.scss';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<div className="container">Hello</div>);
  }
}
```

```
// my-component.scss
@import 'styles/abstracts/variables';

.container {}
```

Assuming `styles/abstracts/_variables.scss` exists under `src`, you could do the following:

```sh
SASS_PATH=src yarn start
```

*OR*

```sh
echo SASS_PATH=src > .env
yarn start
```